# How to make a replica of a live MongoDB and import it to my local environment?

Tags: database, mongodb, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-query, nosql

I want to have in my testing environment a virtually data the same as exist in my live server.

I'm using Google could platform.

How can I import a big sample of each collection keeping in mind that the volume of the live database now is about 100 Giga?

Comment: Can you clarify where you are running the live database
from? Are you running it locally and you would like the
testing database in GCP, or vice versa?

Comment: The live is on GCP and I want to grap it to local

Comment: You can upload your data from the VM instance to Cloud Storage [1]. From there,
you can download the data from Cloud Storage to your local machine.
[1]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp